# Get more information on GridView row click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to get this : When I click on a row, to get a more information about that particular file(every row represents one file from database), and that information is stored in different table... So, how is the best way to do this? Here you have a picture...

[image: jpg]

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    Web_service.WebService1SoapClient service;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        service = new Web_service.WebService1SoapClient();
        BindData();


    }

    protected void BindData()
    {
        string strConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from request", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow r in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (r.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                r.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';";
                r.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";
                r.ToolTip = "Click to select row";
                r.Attributes["onclick"] = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView1, "Select$" + r.RowIndex, true);
            }
        }

        base.Render(writer);
    }

    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindData();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Gridview works really well with the DetailsView Control

Comment: Embedding a control within a gridview is easy - making it look presentable is difficult. It would be far easier to place the details in a modal popup.  I'll have to think on an acceptable embedded answer